# Is it correct to say "I was sure after a year I would get over it"?

Tags: modal-verbs, past-participles, future-in-past

> My pet dog died last summer, she was the only one I had, but I was sure after a year I **would get** over it.

Or should I say *I had get over it* there instead?

Comment: "I would get over it" is correct.  You can also say "...after a year I would *have gotten* over it".

Comment: @KristinaLopez- The difference is that with the OP's sentence you could follow it with, "And I did." while with yours you could only follow with, "But I didn't".

Comment: You cannot say *had get*: there is no such form in English. You might do better over at our sister-site for [ell.se].

Comment: in short, always go for **more shorter sentences** if you need to be clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing grammatically wrong with your sentence, except a bit of possible ambiguity: it's not completely clear whether you mean

> My pet dog died last summer; she was the only one I had, but I was sure **that** after a year I would get over it.

or

> My pet dog died last summer; she was the only one I had, but after a year, I was sure **that** [at some point soon] I would get over it.

Without explicitly including the conjunction, either of those two interpretations are at least possible. Which one is more likely would depend on context.

Comment: An alternative for the second meaning, without needing to rearrange, is just to insert the "that" after "year".

Comment: Yes, the first is clearly expressed as *I was sure that after a year I would get over it.*  And the second is clearly expressed as *I was sure after a year that I would get over it.*